# Lumen v9 missing php artisan schedule command

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, php-8.1, laravel-9

in lumen v8 I had access to `artisan schedule:*` commands.

After upgrading lumen to v9:

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^9",
```

The artisan command console is missing the `artisan schedule:*` commands (like `artisan schedule:run`)!

Were they removed in lumen v9? The documentation does not mention if they were.
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases

Thanks!

Comment: please check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler. this command is already there.

Comment: Thats what I’m saying. Despite the docs, the schedule commands are missing. I’ve used lumen for years, upgraded many times. Never seen this issue. 

If I switch to 8, the schedule commands are back. Switch to 9, they are gone.

Comment: If you are facing a bug with that framework, why not post this on their issue tracker?

Comment: @ShawnNaquin Scheduling exists in the Laravel docs. There’s no mention of it in the Lumen docs. Lumen is pretty much dead these days. There’s absolutely no reason to use it over Laravel. If you need Laravel features, use Laravel.

Comment: @NicoHaase I did file a ticket: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/1224. Originally I thought it was an issue with just my install.

Comment: @MartinBean Scheduling has always been part of Lumen, I've used it through many versions.

Comment: @MartinBean also, lumen is def. not dead. They responded to my issue within hours. The framework was upgraded to v9 just days ago.

Comment: @ShawnNaquin I said “pretty much”. What has Lumen gotten in the past couple of years other than version bumps? Nothing. There are very few use cases where I’d pick Lumen over a pared-back Laravel installation these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an open issue with an awaiting PR:

https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/1224

The framework was not properly calling the schedule class.

edit: the issue has been tagged as a [bug] and since has been resolved!
thanks!